# php header location issues

Tags: php, http-headers

Anyone know why this is happening?

In my code I have the following line this I think is causing problems:

```
header('Location: /var/www/index.php');
```

but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
[Thu Jul 28 22:15:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/account/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost
```

The possible problem line:

```
header('Location: /var/www/index.php');
```

is in a file located at:

```
/var/www/account/oauth/openid/check.php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are directing the browser to an absolute path. This is wrong, you need to use a path relative to the document root. The browser can't see anything outside of the document root.

In your case

```
header('Location: /var/www/index.php');
```

Should probably be:

```
header('Location: /index.php');
```

Since `/var/www/` is your document root.

Comment: Thank you for the fix Lekensteyn. Bit of a thinko!

Answer (score 3):

That will send the browser to: `/var/www/index.php` when you probably just want to send them to `index.php`.

You should use absolute urls with location headers anyways so something like:

```
header('Location: http://mydomain.com/index.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

A URL must be specified in the header() call, you are using a path. Try using the relative location to index.php.

From the [PHP documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept
>   relative URIs.